# How to download file to a specific location using Karate UI I need a file to be saved to customized location not in downloads

Tags: testing, automated-tests, karate

I am automating my web application using Karate UI. I want to save a file from the application to a specific location to validate. By default, it is getting saved in the system downloads folder. How do I change this download path?

I have tried

1. addOptions: ['user.dir','path']
2. userDataDir = "path"

in karate.config(---)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this if you control the user data dir. One of the things you can try is to move a pre-created profile where the system directory is set correctly etc.

Else please assume this is not supported - you are welcome to contribute code and research.

The recommendation is to use Karate's API testing capabilities to download a file to a controlled location: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018365/143475