Karate UI - File download validation in AWS Codepipeline
We are using Karate for our UI application validation. We have a scenario for file download validation where we will validate if the downloaded file is present or not.
We are using Chrome browser and the configuration are set in Karate-config.js.
While running the tests in local, the file is downloaded to local downloads directory and the validation can be easily done. But on running the same tests in AWS codepipeline, the file is getting downloaded but we are not able to locate the file. We are not able to change the download directory in Karate. How can I change the download directory to point some folder in my project directory? Is there any other way to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

the recommendation is to use API testing for file-download: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018365/143475 - but you can see if this alternate approach works: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74391807/143475
