# Suppress Save as dialog pop in Karate by setting the download directory path

Tags: karate

I am trying to suppress the Save as Dialog window by setting the default download directory path. Below is the code i am using, it is still showing the Save as dialog instead of downloading it to the set directory path.

- def customCapabilities =
  """
  {
  "capabilities": {
  "browserName":"chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
  "args":["--start-maximized", "--disable-popup-blocking"],
  "prefs": {
  "download.default_directory":"C:\Users\automation\downloads",
  "download.prompt_for_download":false,
  "safebrowsing.enabled":false
  }
  }
  }
  }
  """

  - configure driver = { type: 'chrome', executable: 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', addOptions: ["--remote-allow-origins=*"], showDriverLog: true, webDriverSession: '#(customCapabilities)' }

Not able to figure what i am doing wrong here

I was expecting the save as dialog not to show and download the file directly in the mentioned downloaded path

Comment: the best info on this subject can be found here (read the comments): https://stackoverflow.com/q/74391807/143475 - anyone is welcome to improve karate or suggest better solutions